# Querying Azure Table Storage from Xamarin for iOS

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin

I'm creating an iOS app using Xamarin Studios for iOS.  I can query data from my Azure Table Storage acct fine from a .NET Web application, but I can't find a good example of how to do the same from Xamarin for iOS.  I do not want to use AZURE SQL DB.  All the examples online are using Mobiles Services and writing to Azure SQL I only want to query a few values from Azure Table Storage. Is there any code samples of how to Read/Write to this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this sample from the head of AzureCAT? http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Use-Table-Storage-in-0b6bcbc7